# Moving mutably borrowed ownership

Tags: rust

My understanding is that a mutable borrower can move ownership to another mutable borrower. But this move seems to be a bit different from moving a non-pointer variable. Let's see an example. Below `p1` gets moved to `p2` when `compute()` is called the first time. But the ownership seems to come back to `p1` after `compute()` returns.

```
fn compute(p2: &mut Point) {
}

fn reset(p1: &mut Point) {
    compute(p1); //OK
    compute(p1); //OK
}
```

This is different from how a regular variable is moved.

```
fn compute(p2:  Point) {
}

fn reset(p1: Point) {
    compute(p1); //OK
    compute(p1); //Compile error
}
```

Now, ownership *does not* revert back to `p1` after the first `compute()` call returns.

Both behaviors are understandable and desirable for many reasons. But I just wanted to confirm my understanding that the two moves are slightly different in nature. Am I right thinking this way?

Comment: "a mutable borrower can move ownership to another mutable borrower" - in my mind, you either *own* an object or you *borrow* one, there's no concept of "borrowed ownership".

Comment: @Shepmaster, references are regular values and they are subjects to ownership rules too. Without reborrowing `&mut` would behave exactly like other noncopyable types (i.e. they could only be moved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct except that in the first instance, the reference is not being moved, it's simply being reborrowed, which is behavior particular to references. Perhaps this clears it up, as it's not an exception within move semantics, but a different behavior altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it is that your first snippet borrows, where as your second transfers ownership.

```
fn compute(p2:  Point) {
    // compute owns p2
} // owned p2 is freed

fn reset(p1: Point) {
    // reset() owns p1
    compute(p1); //Ownership of p1 is transferred to compute()
    compute(p1); //ERROR: p1 has already been freed
}
```

Vice...

```
fn compute(p2:  &Point) {
    // compute is borrowing p2
} // borrowed p2 is given back to owner

fn reset(p1: Point) {
    // reset() owns p1
    compute(&p1); //let compute() borrow p1, then get it back
    compute(&p1); //let compute() re-borrow p1, then give it back
} // owned p1 is freed
```

Comment: They will both transfer ownership since a mutable pointer is an uncopyable type. However, "reborrow" happens for a mutable pointer after the compute() function returns, making the pointer variable usable again. That is my understanding. It will be good to see a more official explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are correct, but I'd like to emphasize two important points in Rust:

- The first point is about the **default behaviour** in Rust: when you pass a non-reference object to a function, it gets moved to the function (**by default!**). That is, the function takes ownership of the object, and the caller can no longer use the object once the function returns. That is what is happening in your second example — because the first call to `compute` takes ownership of the argument passed, you cannot pass the same object in the next call to `compute` as it has been moved.
- If you don't want the default behavior, then you have to **explicitly** instruct the compiler what you want, by saying that you want a copy (of the non-reference object) to be passed to the function. That is easy for the simpler cases — just derive `Clone` and `Copy` for your struct.

  ```
  #[derive(Clone, Copy)]  # instruction for the compiler!
  struct Point {
      x: i32,
      y: i32,
  }
  ```

  If you define your `Point` like this, then even your second code would compile fine. See how it works in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ec1954edff0a064c915ab6f309e89839&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015). I suppose [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b3f56ca95e73ac6e6ec55ca8a42078ce&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) is how you have defined your `Point`.

Comment: When you pass *any* type as a function argument, it is moved, including references. It may happen to be a copy that is moved.

Comment: @Shepmaster: We can use that line of thought as well. But that makes the wordings slightly complicated I guess, because in that case I'd have to add that *"when it is reference which is moved, then the object being referred to by the reference does not move"*.