# Reference passed as parameter is not moved

Tags: rust

```
fn t(x: &mut u8) -> &mut u8 {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 5u8;
    let y = & mut x;
    let z = t(y);
    println!("{}", y);
}
```

Compiling this gives me this error:

```
main.rs:9:20: 9:21 error: cannot borrow `y` as immutable because `*y` is also borrowed as mutable
main.rs:9     println!("{}", y);
```

I would have thought `y` would have been moved during the call to `t` and then back to `z`, resulting in an `error: use of moved value`

1. Why do I get this error message instead?
2. Does Rust automatically create a new borrow instead of passing ownership when references are offered as function parameters?
3. What is the purpose of this behaviour?

Comment: See also [Moving mutably borrowed ownership](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27650188/155423)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a mutable reference to the parameter from your function. However, Rust doesn't know that the method <s>hasn't kept a copy of that pointer</s> didn't return a subsection of that pointer, were it a struct. This means that at any time, the value pointed to might be changed, which is a big no-no in Rust; if it were allowed, then you could easily cause memory errors.

> Does Rust automatically create a new borrow

Yes, Rust "re-borrows" references.

A better example requires a smidge more complexity:

```
struct Thing { a: u8, b: u8 }

fn t(x: &mut Thing) -> &mut u8 {
    &mut x.a
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Thing { a: 5, b: 6 };
    let z = t(&mut x);
    *z = 0;
    // x.a = 0; // cannot assign to `x.a` because it is borrowed
}
```

Here, `t` returns a mutable pointer to a subset of the struct. This means that the entire struct is borrowed, and we cannot change it (except via `z`). Rust applies this logic to all functions, and doesn't try to recognize that your `t` function just returns the same pointer.

Comment: `Rust doesn't know that the method hasn't kept a copy of that pointer` - Since the function has elapsed couldn't it reason that anything in it would be deallocated after it's called?

Comment: The signature of `t` causes that `y` is borrowed mutably as long as `z` exists. And `z` exists until the end of `main`.

Comment: @JV I updated the answer and removed the misleading part you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

By compiling your program with `rustc --pretty=expanded`, we can see that the `println!` macro borrows its argument:

```
#![no_std]
#[macro_use]
extern crate "std" as std;
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::v1::*;
fn t(x: &mut u8) -> &mut u8 { x }

fn main() {
    let mut x = 5u8;
    let y = &mut x;
    let z = t(y);
    ::std::io::stdio::println_args(::std::fmt::Arguments::new({
                                                                  #[inline]
                                                                  #[allow(dead_code)]
                                                                  static __STATIC_FMTSTR:
                                                                         &'static [&'static str]
                                                                         =
                                                                      &[""];
                                                                  __STATIC_FMTSTR
                                                              },
                                                              &match (&y,) { // <----- y is borrowed here
                                                                   (__arg0,)
                                                                   =>
                                                                   [::std::fmt::argument(::std::fmt::String::fmt,
                                                                                         __arg0)],
                                                               }));
}
```